# Collection has been modified; perhaps the enumeration operation is not executed or an item with the same key

Tags: .net, vb.net

I still couldn't find a solution for this question, I have a function that captures the title of the windows processes, and now they are generating exceptions that there is already an item with the same key or the Collection has been modified; perhaps the enumeration operation is not executed, below is the code I am using to capture the processes.

```vb
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" Alias "GetForegroundWindow" () As IntPtr
Private Declare Auto Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function GetLastInputInfo Lib "user32.dll" (ByRef inputStructure As inputInfo) As Boolean
   
<DllImport("USER32.DLL")>
Private Shared Function GetShellWindow() As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("USER32.DLL")>
Private Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As StringBuilder, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("USER32.DLL")>
Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, <Out()> ByRef lpdwProcessId As UInt32) As UInt32
End Function

<DllImport("USER32.DLL")>
Private Shared Function IsWindowVisible(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Private Delegate Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Boolean

<DllImport("USER32.DLL")>
Private Shared Function EnumWindows(ByVal enumFunc As EnumWindowsProc, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Boolean
End Function


Private Structure inputInfo
    Dim structSize As Int32
    Dim tickCount As Int32
End Structure

Private hShellWindow As IntPtr = GetShellWindow()
Private dictWindows As New Dictionary(Of IntPtr, String)
Private currentProcessID As Integer


Public Function GetOpenWindowsFromPID(ByVal processID As Integer) As IDictionary(Of IntPtr, String)
    Try
        dictWindows.Clear()
        currentProcessID = processID
        EnumWindows(AddressOf enumWindowsInternal, 0)
        Return dictWindows
    Catch ex As Exception
        writeExeption(ex)
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function

Private Function enumWindowsInternal(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Boolean
    Try
        If hWnd <> hShellWindow Then
            Dim windowPid As UInt32
            If Not IsWindowVisible(hWnd) Then
                Return True
            End If
            Dim length As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd)
            If length = 0 Then
                Return True
            End If
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, windowPid)
            If windowPid <> currentProcessID Then
                Return True
            End If
            Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder(length)
            GetWindowText(hWnd, stringBuilder, length + 1)
            If Not dictWindows.ContainsKey(hWnd) Then
                dictWindows.Add(hWnd, stringBuilder.ToString)
            Else
                Return False
            End If

        End If
            Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        writeExeption(ex)
    End Try
    Return False
End Function


Public Function GetCaption() As String
    Try
        Dim Caption As New StringBuilder(256)
        Dim hWnd As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()
        GetWindowText(hWnd, Caption, Caption.MaxCapacity)
        Return Caption.ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        writeExeption(ex)
    End Try
    Return ""

End Function

Public Function getApplications(ByVal currentWindow As String) As String
    dictWindows.Clear()
    Dim p() As Process = Process.GetProcesses()
    Try
        If p.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To p.Count - 1
                Dim windows As IDictionary(Of IntPtr, String) = GetOpenWindowsFromPID(p(i).Id)
                For j = 0 To windows.Count - 1

                    If windows.Values(j).ToString = currentWindow Then
                        'Console.WriteLine("Caption: " & windows.Values(j).ToString & " 

                        If p(i).ProcessName.ToString().Trim() = "Taskmgr" Then
                            If reported_task_manager = False Then
                                record_task_manager()
                            End If
                        Else
                            reported_task_manager = False
                        End If
                        Return p(i).ProcessName.ToString()
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        writeExeption(ex)
        Console.WriteLine("Erro GetApplication: " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
    Return "TaskBar"
End Function
```

I've already tried to debug the process but I couldn't identify the cause of the error, the function should always return the window title of each active process.

The error is caused by this piece of code:

```
GetWindowText(hWnd, stringBuilder, length + 1) 
If Not dictWindows.ContainsKey(hWnd) Then
 dictWindows.Add(hWnd, stringBuilder.ToString)
else 
  Return False
End If
```

ThrowArgumentException - An item with the same key has already been added or Collection has been modified; perhaps the enumeration operation is not performed. ThrowInvalidOperationException

Comment: Where is the error and what is the error?

Comment: The error is caused by this piece of code:
  GetWindowText(hWnd, stringBuilder, length + 1)
             If Not dictWindows.ContainsKey(hWnd) Then
                 dictWindows.Add(hWnd, stringBuilder.ToString)
             else
                 Return False
             End If
ThrowArgumentException - An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: or Collection has been modified; perhaps the enumeration operation is not performed. ThrowInvalidOperationException

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Please edit your question and provide a the FULL and CLEAR explanation that you should have in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in how the `EnumWindows()` method calls `enumWindowsInternal()`. It appears the calls happen via a mechansim such that multiple calls to `enumWindowsInternal()` might seem to run in parallel (I'm not sure this actually happens... likely more of an interrupt/resume situation).

With that in mind, it's possible one instance of the method begins checking the dictionary via `ContainsKey()` (which uses a type of enumeration), and then before that can finish another instance of the method tries to `Add()` to the dictionary. This modifies the dictionary during the enumeration, which is not allowed as indicated by the error.

The is exacerbated by the way in which `dictWindow` is scoped to the class level, instead of in a single method. It could also be the entire operation could be triggered additional times before prior runs completed, such that a single class-level dictionary would have a similar result.

The code below *might* help, depending on how `TryAdd()` works:

```
Public Function GetOpenWindowsFromPID(ByVal processID As Integer) As IDictionary(Of IntPtr, String)

    Dim result As New Dictionary(Of IntPtr, String)
    Dim enumWindowsInternal As Func(Of IntPtr, Integer, Boolean) = _
        Function(hWnd, lParam)
            Try
                If hWnd = hShellWindow Then Return True
                If Not IsWindowVisible(hWnd) Then Return True
 
                Dim length As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd) 
                If length = 0 Then Return True

                Dim windowPid As UInt32
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, windowPid)
                If windowPid <> processID Then Return True

                Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder(length)
                GetWindowText(hWnd, stringBuilder, length + 1)

                result.TryAdd(hWnd, stringBuilder.ToString())

            Catch ex As Exception
                writeExeption(ex)
            End Try
            Return False
        End Function

    Try        
        EnumWindows(AddressOf enumWindowsInternal, 0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        writeExeption(ex)
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

The above converts `enumWindowsInternal` to a delegate local to the outer method. This in turn allows us to use a new local instance of the dictionary, which `enumWindowsInternal` can now reference directly via a closure. We can also return the dictionary to the calling code, as method signature indicates was the plan in the first place.

The main thing to understand is every call to `GetOpenWindowsFromPID()` will now have its own private Dictionary to play with. Additionally, we removed the check to `ContainsKey()`, and instead replaced `Add()` with `TryAdd()`.

While I was here, I also inverted some of the conditional expression so I could convert them to guard clauses. This allowed me to shorten the method and reduce nesting.

Some of the other surrounding code will also need to change to accommodate this new structure, but I'll leave that for the OP.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I just applied your suggestion, but it is giving an error in Tryadd, because I do not have this function, another situation is that in AddressOf it says that it has to be used without parentheses, but when I remove them, it does not it's recognized

Comment: TryAdd() requires .Net core. If you only have framework, you'll need to do something like `lock` around the `ContainKey()`, / `Add()` calls.

Comment: Joel Coehoorn I put the code running, but it returned an error from Tryadd and also from the addressof as it was called, the Framework I'm using is net 4.8, I made some modifications to get it to work but the result was the same, I believe that the problem not being able to make your code work either because it was written for .net core, because the way the enumWindowsInternal function was placed as a delegate, the AddressOf cannot see inside the same function, any other ideas?